# IE6 and box model with padding

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css

I have a box that is width:600px
i like to have text left, with padding of 20px
that box is flot with another at it side (sidebar/content)
in other browser it play fine, content-sidebar with define

in ie6 it see the content to be 600 + 20, witch push the sidebat to the bottom...

How do you use padding, that work in all the browser including ie6

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the correct DOCTYPE set? From what I remember, IE6 only uses the broken box model if it falls back to quirks mode. ([Wikipedia seems to agree with me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug))

Comment: This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!

Comment: Could you provide a small test case on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: andre In that case, I can't see how it can be the box model. Could it be the [IE6 "drop float" problem](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html)? Do you maybe have content that is forcing your box to expand beyond its normal boundary in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are free to use hacks, use underscore hack.

```
_width: 560px; // targets ie6 only
```

otherwise

add a wrapper div and add padding to that div

```
<div style="width: 600px">
  <div style="padding: 0 20px">
     bla bla
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont like hack, but this one nice... and simple !

Answer (score 0):

IE will see the box as 560px + 20px left padding + 20px right padding to equal 600, rather than 600px + 20px left padding + 20px right padding (as browsers should see it). The default behaviour of the box model is to take the width of the box and then add padding and margins to it.

The best way to target IE6 is to use a conditional comment (http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/), and then in that stylesheet set the box as width:560px. I'm assuming you don’t have margins but if you do you need to subtract those from the overall width, too.

Comment: it's not a good habit to hack the stylesheet and add conditional... i have see a lot of site with many many css one for each browser... but some super big site...have none... so, there must be a way... still looking